# Wix - set file read access

Tags: iis, wix

I am looking into a way of setting read access on a specific file for a web application (where all files read option is set to be false--unchecked in IIS) deployed with Wix. Is it a possible option at all or I am asking the question in a wrong way?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That level of granularity is not supported by the WiX toolset's IIS custom actions today. It'd be cool if someone implemented it and contributed back to the community.